# In finitely generated group, if $\{H_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an infinite sequence of distinct cyclic group then $\cap{H_n}=\{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

I think it is true. But I don't know the proof. And what about in countably generated group? More general, in which group it is true. Any kind of help will be appreciable.

Comment: For the countably generated case consider $G=\Bbb Q$ and $H_n=\frac1n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ok, Good. But what about in a finitely generated group?

Comment: Every countable group embeds into into a finitely generated group. Hence from the previous countable example you could deduce mechanically a finitely generated one. For instance, in the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,m)=\langle t,x| txt^{-1}=x^m\rangle$ for given $m\ge 2$, take $H_n=\langle t^{-n}xt^n\rangle$.

Comment: It's true in every group in which every nontrivial cyclic subgroup has a cyclic centralizer. This holds in torsion-free hyperbolic groups, among others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let 
$$G=\Bbb Z\rtimes\Bbb Z$$
as induced by the only non-trivial action,
or if you prefer
$$G=\langle \,a,b\mid ba=a^{-1}b\,\rangle,$$
or completely down to earth:
$$G=\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$$ with multiplication rule
$$ (a,b)\cdot (c,d):=(a+(-1)^bc,b+d).$$
Now let $H_n$ be generated by $(n,1)$. Then $(n,1)\cdot(n,1)=(0,2)\in H_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful example.